# How to access pages ids of all the pages in notion?

Tags: python, notion-api

I'm working on an notion integration which requires me to know all possible page ids in notion not just root even it's children. Is there a way to access all the pages?

The only way I found till now was using the search API but it only sends 100 items.

I'm using the latest notion API last updated on - `2022-06-28`

Comment: I think it is not possible